# A way to replace the object type for a field in a POJO that extends another POJO

Tags: java, lombok

Lets say I have class

```
public class ParentClass {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private List<AnotherParentPojo> evses;
}

public class AnotherChildPojo extends AnotherParentPojo {
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    private String fieldC;
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    private List<AnotherChildPojo> evses;
}
```

However this leads to the error "both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other" in the ChildClass. I am aware its not possible to override a field but is there any way to achieve this without having to change ParentClass or AnotherParentPojo? I only have control over the ChildClass and AnotherChildPojo

Comment: The given example is not correct. Please add the methods as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java name clash, have the same erasure, neither hides the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002965/java-name-clash-have-the-same-erasure-neither-hides-the-other)

Comment: I am using @Data annotation, its just simple setters and getters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned `@Data` annotation I assume, you are using lombok [1].

The issue issue that `ParentClass` and its child `ChildClass` basically declare same setters/getters but with different type erasure.

Even though you cannot see them, they are there (lombok magic).

In order to understand what is happening, I advise you to de-lombok the actual code.

```
public class ParentClass {

...

    public List<AnotherParentPojo> getEvses() {
        return evses;
    }

    public void setEvses(List<AnotherParentPojo> evses) {
        this.evses = evses;
    }

...

}
```

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
...

    public List<AnotherChildPojo> getEvses() {
        return evses;
    }

    public void setEvses(List<AnotherChildPojo> evses) {
        this.evses = evses;
    }
...
}
```

### Solution

Solution might be to just rename one of the "clashing" fields or turn off generation of setter and getter using `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)` `@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)` annotations for particular field.

---

[1] https://projectlombok.org/

Comment: So we are following a contract and the response returned must have evses so renaming the field may not be an option. What would turning off setters and getters achieve? I still need to be able to access the evses

Comment: By turning off setter and getter, you can make your own getter and setter for particular field in order to avoid name clash.

Comment: @Ahmed, why renaming is not an option?  `ChildClass` inherits `getEvses/setEvses` from `ParentClass` with `List<AnotherParentPojo>` and has its own `getEvsesChild/setEvsesChild` dealing with `List<AnotherChildPojo>` data.  It is not a breaking change for interface but rather an extension.

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood. I was able to rename the getter and setter method name so it doesn't conflict with the parent's class getter/setter and kept the field name as evses and it worked smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If Lombok's `@Data` annotation is applied to both `ParentClass` and `ChildClass`, appropriate getters/setters are generated:

```java
// ParentClass
public void setEvses(List<AnotherParentPojo> list) {...}
public List<AnotherParentPojo> getEvses() {...}
```

and the name clash occurs in `ChildClass` as it is inherited from `ParentClass`

```java
// ChildClass
public void setEvses(List<AnotherChildPojo> list) {...}
public List<AnotherChildPojo> getEvses() {...}
```

If access to `ChildClass` is available, the simplest solution would be just to rename its `evses` field, thus renaming the getters/setters and resolving the name conflict.